# Could not find the onCreate() method

Tags: java, android, admob, ads, oncreate

I want to add Admob to a project. In the main java class I couldn't find the `onCreate()` method to add the Adview and `AdRequest` in order to initialize the Google Mobile Ads SDK

```
package *****************

import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.OpenableColumns;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.listener.OnLoadCompleteListener;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.listener.OnPageChangeListener;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.scroll.DefaultScrollHandle;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.shockwave.pdfium.PdfDocument;

import org.androidannotations.annotations.AfterViews;
import org.androidannotations.annotations.EActivity;
import org.androidannotations.annotations.NonConfigurationInstance;
import org.androidannotations.annotations.OnActivityResult;
import org.androidannotations.annotations.OptionsItem;
import org.androidannotations.annotations.OptionsMenu;
import org.androidannotations.annotations.ViewById;

import java.util.List;

@EActivity(R.layout.activity_main)
@OptionsMenu(R.menu.options)

public class PDFViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnPageChangeListener, OnLoadCompleteListener {

    private static final String TAG = PDFViewActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private final static int REQUEST_CODE = 42;
    public static final int PERMISSION_CODE = 42042;

    public static final String SAMPLE_FILE = "sample.pdf";
    public static final String READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE";


    @ViewById
    PDFView pdfView;

    @NonConfigurationInstance
    Uri uri;

    @NonConfigurationInstance
    Integer pageNumber = 0;

    String pdfFileName;

    @OptionsItem(R.id.pickFile)
    void pickFile() {
        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    new String[]{READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    PERMISSION_CODE
            );

            return;
        }

        launchPicker();
    }

    void launchPicker() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("application/pdf");
        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            //alert user that file manager not working
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.toast_pick_file_error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @AfterViews
    void afterViews() {
        if (uri != null) {
            displayFromUri(uri);
        } else {
            displayFromAsset(SAMPLE_FILE);
        }
        setTitle(pdfFileName);
    }

    private void displayFromAsset(String assetFileName) {
        pdfFileName = assetFileName;

        pdfView.fromAsset(SAMPLE_FILE)
                .defaultPage(pageNumber)
                .onPageChange(this)
                .enableAnnotationRendering(true)
                .onLoad(this)
                .scrollHandle(new DefaultScrollHandle(this))
                .load();
    }

    private void displayFromUri(Uri uri) {
        pdfFileName = getFileName(uri);

        pdfView.fromUri(uri)
                .defaultPage(pageNumber)
                .onPageChange(this)
                .enableAnnotationRendering(true)
                .onLoad(this)
                .scrollHandle(new DefaultScrollHandle(this))
                .load();
    }

    @OnActivityResult(REQUEST_CODE)
    public void onResult(int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            uri = intent.getData();
            displayFromUri(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageChanged(int page, int pageCount) {
        pageNumber = page;
        setTitle(String.format("%s %s / %s", pdfFileName, page + 1, pageCount));
    }

    public String getFileName(Uri uri) {
        String result = null;
        if (uri.getScheme().equals("content")) {
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
            try {
                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    result = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                }
            } finally {
                if (cursor != null) {
                    cursor.close();
                }
            }
        }
        if (result == null) {
            result = uri.getLastPathSegment();
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void loadComplete(int nbPages) {
        PdfDocument.Meta meta = pdfView.getDocumentMeta();
        Log.e(TAG, "title = " + meta.getTitle());
        Log.e(TAG, "author = " + meta.getAuthor());
        Log.e(TAG, "subject = " + meta.getSubject());
        Log.e(TAG, "keywords = " + meta.getKeywords());
        Log.e(TAG, "creator = " + meta.getCreator());
        Log.e(TAG, "producer = " + meta.getProducer());
        Log.e(TAG, "creationDate = " + meta.getCreationDate());
        Log.e(TAG, "modDate = " + meta.getModDate());

        printBookmarksTree(pdfView.getTableOfContents(), "-");

    }

    public void printBookmarksTree(List<PdfDocument.Bookmark> tree, String sep) {
        for (PdfDocument.Bookmark b : tree) {

            Log.e(TAG, String.format("%s %s, p %d", sep, b.getTitle(), b.getPageIdx()));

            if (b.hasChildren()) {
                printBookmarksTree(b.getChildren(), sep + "-");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Listener for response to user permission request
     *
     * @param requestCode  Check that permission request code matches
     * @param permissions  Permissions that requested
     * @param grantResults Whether permissions granted
     */
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[],
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                launchPicker();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: problem solved just add the call @Afterviews like this

```
@AfterViews
void afterViews() {
    if (uri != null) {
        displayFromUri(uri);
    } else {
        displayFromAsset(SAMPLE_FILE);
    }
    setTitle(pdfFileName);

    MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "app-id");

    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

P.S. I am new to programming.

Comment: You must create the `onCreate` method. You should study more about the Android Framework (specially Activity Lifecycle) before starting with the other features like AdMob.

Comment: I tried to add the method, the app crashes at launch

Comment: Can you post the logcat shown when the app crashes?

Comment: okay, logcat added

Comment: That logcat isn't really helpful, sorry. You might want to try and understand that the code you found doesn't use `onCreate` because it doesn't need to. You need to understand how Android-Annotations works though. That `@AfterViews` annotation essentially is the code that runs following `onCreate` https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/wiki/Injecting-Views#afterviews

Comment: @cricket_007 I solved the problem, thank you sir

Comment: @MounirLardjem If you've managed to fix the issue, please post it as an answer and self-accept so it'll help others reading this question in the future.

Comment: @MichaelDodd done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, just put it in @Afterviews like this:

```
@AfterViews
void afterViews() {
if (uri != null) {
    displayFromUri(uri);
} else {
    displayFromAsset(SAMPLE_FILE);
}
setTitle(pdfFileName);

MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "app-id");

AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I'd recommend taking a look at the [Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html) documentation. If there is no `onCreate()` method in the code you've supplied you'll need to add the method yourself. Ethics of *why you'd modify an Apache 2.0-licensed product to only insert adverts* aside, in your case it would be

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "app-id");

    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

Also note that the code supplied in that Activity makes heavy use of [Android Annotations](https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations), I'd recommend spending some time familiarising yourself with some more vanilla code before moving on to time-saving libraries such as this.

Comment: I tried to add the method, the app crashes at launch.  
I noticed also that there is a generated activity that contains the method (I added the code above), but I can't edit it because it's generated

Comment: In which case, can you edit your original question to include the logcat that is produced when the app crashes?

Comment: Thanks to @Jake_ for pointing out that I forgot to call the `super` method. Give the updated answer a try, though your logcat looks completely unrelated.

Comment: I added the super method, the app crashes at launch, I updated the logcat

Comment: Unfortunately that logcat isn't much use either. The line you're looking for will begin with `E/` after the timestamp, and will likely have the phrases `Exception` and `caused by` in it.

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm aware that `onCreate()` doesn't need implementing, but OP specifically mentioned that they were looking for the `onCreate()` method, which is why I gave this example.